# Fix the TS2345: Argument of type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLInputElement'

Tags: ionic-framework, google-maps-autocomplete

I'm trying to setup **Google Maps Places Autocomplete** in an new Ionic app.

here is the problem. On the first search, I got this error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'place_id' of undefined
```

and this error in the terminal:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLInputElement'
```

However, on the second search I get the place_id without any error.

**Here is my (simplified) .ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { google } from "google-maps";
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({...})
export class AddaddressPage implements OnInit {

  autocomplete:any;

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
            this.autocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);
        });
    }

    fillInAddress() {
      var place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place);
      console.log(place.place_id);
    }

}
```

and the input I use:

```
<input id="autocomplete" type="text" (change)="fillInAddress()" />
```

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around, here is the trick! ViewChild and Ion-input are needed.

**.html**

```
<ion-input #autocomplete type="text"></ion-input>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { google } from "google-maps";
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component(...)
export class AddaddressPage implements OnInit {

  googleAutocomplete:any;

  @ViewChild('autocomplete') autocompleteInput: ElementRef;

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {  }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.autocompleteInput.getInputElement().then((el)=>{
                this.googleAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(el);
                this.googleAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);
                this.googleAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
                    var place = this.googleAutocomplete.getPlace();
                    console.log(place);
                    console.log(place.place_id);
                });
            })

        });
    }

}
```